# How can I access the content of this "object"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to access an api (xboxapi.com) right now. It works so far - I get an object back in console.log from xbox_gamercard.

```
{"gamertag":"my_xbox_gamertag","name":"xxx","location":"xxx","bio":"xxx"}
```

But if I want to output the gamertag via `console.log(xbox_gamercard.gamertag),` I only get an "undefined" back.

Can you help me how to get access to the contents of the object?

```js
var xbox = require('node-xbox')("my api key");

xbox.profile.gamercard("my xbox id", function(err, xbox_gamercard){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(xbox_gamercard);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try logging  `console.log(typeof xbox_gamercard);`. I am guessing it is a string, and you need to parse it (`JSON.parse`) before accessing its property.

Comment: You are getting back an API call so it must be a string. Do `let data = JSON.parse(xbox_gamercard)` and then do `data["gamertag"]` because the data must be string and you have to parse it

Comment: @Nisarg thx, this was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string you receive into a JSON object using `JSON.parse` and access the property of the object

```js
var a='{"gamertag":"my_xbox_gamertag","name":"xxx","location":"xxx","bio":"xxx"}'
var b=JSON.parse(a)
console.log(b.gamertag)
```

Comment: That is not the case here. The OP is getting a string back, they don't have it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As [@weegee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10967889/weegee) said, use `JSON.parse`. Here is an example:

```js
var xbox = require('node-xbox')('my api key');

xbox.profile.gamercard('my xbox id', function(err, xbox_gamercard) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var obj = JSON.parse(xbox_gamercard);
        console.log(obj.gamertag);
    }
})
```